# How to determine Multivalued Dependency MVD (transitive rule)?

Tags: database, normalization

I have some difficulties to determine MVD for the following Relation

```
 R=(A,B,C,D,E) where A->>B and B->>D
```

Given the following tuples:

```
 (0,1,2,3,4) and (0,5,6,7,8)
```

I would like to determine `all` tuples which may complete the relation.

As I understood, if the tuples `t(A)=u(A)` there must be third tuple  `v(A)=t(A)` and  `v(B)=t(B )` a fourth tuples `w(A)=t(A)` and `w(B)=u(B)`

So I tried:

```
       A B C D E
   t   0 1 2 3 4
   u   0 5 6 7 8
   v   0 1 2 3 4
   w   0 5 6 7 8
```

However, I suppose I might miss something (aka transitivity). Because non of the tuples (`v`and `w`) is included in the set:

```
   1.(0,1,2,7,4)
   2.(0,1,2,3,8)
   3.(0,1,6,3,4)
   4.(0,5,2,7,8)
```

where at least one of the tuples must be true. I just cant bring it together and would appreciate any help! Regarding transitivity, I figured out that `A->>B` and `B->>D` so `A->>(D-B)` or that `A->>BD` but I just cant get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, with the given MVDs, is misleading to make an example with two tuples as:

```
 (0,1,2,3,4) and (0,5,6,7,8)
```

since there is no way of saying, from the example, if there are multiple values of `D` for a certain `B` (you have two different values of `B`) and there can be other multivalued dependencies, since you have different values for `C` and `E` given the same value of `A`.

To show this more clearly, I’ll try to rephrase your example with different, more concrete, data. Suppose that your relation is about multisite Companies, and the attributes are:

```
A company name  (N)  (a company has a single name)
B site          (S)  (a company can have multiple sites)
C website       (W)  (a company has a single web site)
D phone number  (P)  (a company site can have multiple phone numbers)
E CEO           (E)  (a company has a single CEO)
```

So we can rewrite the schema as `C(N,S,W,P,E)`, and `N->>S`, and `S->>P`, as in your example. This simply means that you can have several sites for each company, and several phones for each site.

Suppose that the company `N1` has two sites, `S1` and `S2`, and tho phone numbers for each site: `P11` and `P12` for site `S1` and `P21` and `P22` for site `S2`. So at least the following two tuples must be present in `C`:

```
 (N1, S1, W1, P11, E1)  and (N1, S2, W2, P21, E1)
```

but, as in the case of your example, knowing only these two tuples does not give any other information about the existence of other tuples (this is since there could be only two sites with just a (single) different phone for each site.
Instead, from the description of the concrete example, we know that in `C` all the following tuples *must* be present:

```
N    S    W    P    E
N1   S1   W1   P11  E1
N1   S2   W1   P21  E1
N1   S1   W1   P12  E1
N1   S2   W1   P22  E1
```

Finally, regarding transitivity, you are correct saying that from `A->>B` and `B->>D` one can infer that `A->>(D-B)` but *not* that `A->>BD` (it is a completely different thing!)